# Proper implementation of signal handler and multithreading (pthread)

Tags: c, posix, pthreads, signal-handling

I am trying to implement a "proper" signal handler that works correctly for multiple threads, and to be as C-standard-conforming and POSIX-conforming as possible. The below is my implementation, any thoughts or bugs?:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>

volatile sig_atomic_t e_flag = 0;

static void signal_handler(int signo) {
    char msg[] = "Signal caught\n";
    write(STDIN_FILENO, msg, strlen(msg));
    e_flag = 1;
}

void* event_loop(void* param) {
    int tid = *((int*)param);
    size_t iter_count = 0;
    while (e_flag == 0) {
        ++ iter_count;
        printf("Th %d: Event loop is running now, iterated %lu times ...\n",
            tid, iter_count);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < tid + 1 && e_flag == 0; ++ i) {
            sleep(1);
        }
    }
    size_t* ret = (size_t*)malloc(sizeof(size_t));
    if (ret != NULL) {
        *ret = iter_count;
    } else {
        perror("malloc()");
    }
    return ret;
}

int main() {
    if (signal(SIGINT, signal_handler) == SIG_ERR) {
        perror("signal()");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("A signal handler is installed, "
        "press Ctrl+C to exit event loop threads gracefully.\n");

    pthread_t threads[8];
    size_t running_thread_count = 0;
    /* It is not guaranteed that pthread_t is an int type, so we'd better
    create our own thread_id*/
    int tids[sizeof(threads) / sizeof(threads[0])];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(threads) / sizeof(threads[0]); ++i) {
        tids[i] = i;
        int err_no;
        // pthread_create() doesn't set errno,
        // we need to catch its retval manually
        if ((err_no = pthread_create(
            &threads[i], NULL, event_loop, (void *)&tids[i])) != 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "pthread_create() failed: %d(%s), "
                "the program exits now", err_no, strerror(err_no));
            if ((err_no = raise(SIGINT)) != 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "even raise() failed: %d(%s), "
                    "the program exits UNgracefully",
                    err_no, strerror(err_no));
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            break;
        }
        ++running_thread_count;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < running_thread_count; ++i) {
        size_t* ret;
        int err_no;
        // pthread_join() doesn't set errno,
        // we need to catch its retval manually
        if ((err_no = pthread_join(threads[i], (void**)&ret)) != 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "pthread_join() failed: %d(%s), "
                "but there is nothing much we can do",
                err_no, strerror(err_no));
        } else {
            if (ret != NULL) {
                printf("Th %lu exited, iterated: %lu times\n", i, *ret);
                free(ret);
            } else {
                printf("Th %lu exited, but retval is not set as expected\n", i);
            }
        }
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Corresponding `Makefile` in case you would like to compile:

```
OPTS = -O2 -Wall -pedantic -Wc++-compat
CC = gcc

main:   
    $(CC) main.c -o main.out $(OPTS) -lrt -lpthread
```

I also included ChatGPT 3.5's reply here, just for fun (I am aware that Stack Exchange bans using ChatGPT in answers, but I believe it doesn't ban it in questions?):

Overall, your implementation looks good and follows the best practices for handling signals in multi-threaded programs.

However, there are a few things you may want to consider:

1. Don't use `printf()` in a signal handler: According to the POSIX standard, the signal handler should avoid calling any function that is not async-signal-safe. `printf()` is not one of them, so it's recommended to use write() instead.

   // Well, I didn't do this
2. Use `volatile sig_atomic_t` for shared variable updates: You already used `volatile sig_atomic_t` for the flag variable e_flag, which is good for atomic updates. However, you also used `size_t` for iterating the threads, which is not guaranteed to be atomic. It's better to use volatile `sig_atomic_t` in this case as well.

   // The first half is already done, what does it mean in the 2nd half?
3. Check the return value of `write()`: `write()` may not write all the characters, especially if it's interrupted by a signal. You should check the return value to make sure all characters are written. This applies to any function that may be interrupted by a signal.

   If write() returns a value less than the size of the buffer, it means that not all characters were written. You should write the remaining characters in a loop until all of them are written. Here's an example of how to do this:

   ```
   static void signal_handler(int signo) {
       const char msg[] = "Signal caught\n";
       size_t len = sizeof(msg) - 1; // exclude null terminator
       size_t written = 0;
       while (written < len) {
           ssize_t ret = write(STDOUT_FILENO, msg + written, len - written);
           if (ret == -1 && errno == EINTR) {
               continue;
           }
           if (ret == -1) {
               perror("write()");
               break;
           }
           written += ret;
       }
       e_flag = 1;
   }
   ```

   // This seems a valid point
4. Don't exit in the signal handler: Exiting in the signal handler is not recommended, as it may cause undefined behavior. Also, `raise()` is not guaranteed to work in a signal handler. It's better to set the flag variable and let the main program exit gracefully.

   // Well, I didn't do this
5. Don't catch all errors in `pthread_create()`: `pthread_create()` may fail for reasons other than `ENOMEM`. You should check the return value and exit or continue the loop accordingly.

   // `man pthread_create` doesn't list `ENOMEM` as an error. Possible errors are `EAGAIN`, `EINVAL` and `EPERM` only. But the point it raises does appears to be worth exploring.
6. Use `size_t` for thread indexes: Since `pthread_create()` expects a `void*` parameter, you can pass any type of pointer to it. It's better to use `size_t` for the thread index, which is the same type as the array index. This avoids type casting and potential errors.

   // A valid point, fixed.

Comment: In `signal_handler`, did you mean to write to `STDOUT_FILENO` or `STDERR_FILENO`?

Comment: I don't know if `-pedantic` is a superset of this but I always throw in `-Wextra`.

Comment: @DanielWalker my original intent is `STDOUT_FILENO` as I usually dont consider signals as error (like Ctrl+C), what do you think? any conventions?

Comment: @DanielWalker, `-Wextra` [added](https://github.com/alex-lt-kong/the-nitty-gritty/blob/main/c-cpp/common/04_posix-api/03_signal-handler/2_multithreading.c)

Comment: That’s up to you but stdin is for input only.

Comment: @DanielWalker oh yes, it should be `STDOUT_FILENO`, odd it still works even if I write to `STDIN_FILENO`..

Comment: In a shell on a TTY, it's normal that fds 0, 1, and 2 are all duplicates of each other, referring to the same read/write open of the TTY.  `write(0` breaks if you redirect input from anything, then fd 0 will be read-only.  I'd almost be tempted to fix it, and edit the answer which quotes that code, since it's a simply brain-fart that orthogonal to the design or implementation of your program.  It's pure distraction from that issue, not something other people are going to be wondering about in their own code.

Comment: What an excellent example of why you shouldn't rely on ChatGPT for technical advice!

Comment: @JohnBollinger but my feeling is exactly opposite--it does raise some valid points, though not 100% accurate. In Microsoft's term, this is called "[usefully wrong](https://www.cnbc.com/2023/03/16/microsoft-justifies-ais-usefully-wrong-answers.html)" ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: You should not be calling `write()` in a signal handler.

Comment: @MartinYork any reason? `man signal-safety` says `write()` is safe in a signal handler.

Comment: @D.J.Elkind Seems I am wrong. But I thought it would be unsafe as it may be interrupted by a signal.

Comment: @MartinYork I believe the `printf()` family is unsafe, but `write()` is okay.

Answer (score 11):

### Use the correct prototype for `main()`:

The C standard only defines two prototypes for `main()`:

```
1) int main (void)
2) int main (int argc, char *argv[])
    Or 
   int main (int argc, char **argv)
```

The rest may be provided as an extension and are not portable.

### `signal(2)` is deprecated and unportable:

From the Linux man page:

> WARNING: the behavior of signal() varies across UNIX versions,
> and has also varied historically across different versions of
> Linux.

The only portable use of `signal()` is to change the signal's disposition to `SIG_IGN` or `SIG_DFL`. Avoid it's use; consider `sigaction(2)` instead.

### `exit(3)` performs normal program termination:

```
fprintf(stderr, "even raise() failed: %d(%s), "
                 "the program exits UNgracefully",
                  err_no, strerror(err_no));
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

Perhaps you're looking for `abort(3)`?

### The correct format specifier for `size_t` is `%zu`:

From the C standard:

> If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding
> conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

```
//printf("Th %lu exited, but retval is not set as expected\n", i);
 
printf("Th %zu exited, but retval is not set as expected\n", i);
```

### Do not cast the result of `malloc(3)` and family:

```
//size_t* ret = (size_t*)malloc(sizeof(size_t));
size_t* ret = malloc(sizeof(size_t));
```

`malloc()` returns a generic `void *` that is implicitly converted to any other pointer type. As such, it's result need not be casted and only serves to clutter one's code.

**Minor**:

```
char msg[] = "Signal caught\n";
write(STDIN_FILENO, msg, strlen(msg));
```

`msg`'s length can be determined at compile-time with `sizeof`:

```
/* This seems to be a bug. Are we 
 * writing to STDIN_FILENO? — Peter Cordes
 */ 
write (STDIN_FILENO, msg, sizeof msg - 1);
```

Allocate to the referenced type:

```
size_t* ret = malloc(sizeof *ret);
```

Use more `const`:

```
//char msg[] = "Signal caught\n";
const char msg[] = "Signal caught\n";
```

`param` is not changed anywhere in `event_loop`, it deserves to be `const`-qualified:

```
void* event_loop(const void* param) {
   const  int tid = *param;
```

I do not have a compiler at hand, but there's a type mismatch here:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < tid + 1 && e_flag == 0; ++ i) {
```

`i` is an unsigned integer type, whereas `tid` is a signed integer type. Enable more compiler warnings.

The return value of `write(2)` is left unchecked.

The inclusion of `string.h` is not required.

As for compliancy to the ISO C standard, it doesn't know anything about `write()`.

C11 §7.14.1.1 The signal function ¶5 specifies the rules:

> If the signal occurs other than as the result of calling the abort or raise
> function, the behavior is undefined if the signal handler refers to
> any object with static or thread storage duration that is not a
> lock-free atomic object other than by assigning a value to an object
> declared as volatile sig_atomic_t, or the signal handler calls any
> function in the standard library other than the abort function, the
> _Exit function, the quick_exit function, or the signal function with the first argument equal to the signal number corresponding to the
> signal that caused the invocation of the handler. Furthermore, if such
> a call to the signal function results in a SIG_ERR return, the value
> of errno is indeterminate.

Comment: All the suggestions until `Do not cast the result of malloc(3) and family:` are added to my revised version [here](https://github.com/alex-lt-kong/the-nitty-gritty/blob/main/c-cpp/common/04_posix-api/03_signal-handler/2_multithreading.c). On the `malloc()` issue, if I dont add a cast, gcc complains: "warning: request for implicit conversion from ‘void *’ to ‘size_t *’ {aka ‘long unsigned int *’} not permitted in C++ [-Wc++-compat]". As I use both C and C++ , I tend to turn on `-Wc++-compat` so that I "use the subset of C that is valid in C++".

Comment: I made two relatively big changes to the `signal_handler()` part [here](https://github.com/alex-lt-kong/the-nitty-gritty/blob/7f7313292cce0008ac633920b4e6661af783cfdb/c-cpp/common/04_posix-api/03_signal-handler/2_multithreading.c#L11-L28). 1st: I make the C-string dynamic; 2nd: the `write()` has its error check, based on the comments from you and ChatGPT.

Comment: On "`msg`'s length can be determined at compile-time with `sizeof`": my original thought is that my `strlen()` will be optimized away and replaced by a constant (I didn't check the disassembly though)

Comment: `#include<string.h>` is needed by `strerror()`

Comment: On `const`, I can't use it for `event_loop()` given how `pthread_create()` is defined: `warning: passing argument 3 of ‘pthread_create’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   79 |             &threads[i], NULL, event_loop, (void *)&tids[i])) != 0)`

Comment: On "As for compliancy to the ISO C standard, it doesn't know anything about write().", my understanding is that C standard/C committee has a very conservative view on what we should do in a `signal_handler(), illustrated by quotes like this: "the C89 Committee concluded that about the only thing a strictly conforming program can do in a signal handler is to assign a value to a volatile static variable which can be written uninterruptedly and promptly return." I use `write()` because it is listed in `man signal-safety` as a safe function to be called inside a `signal_handler()`

Comment: @D.J.Elkind:  With optimization enabled, `strlen(msg)` is evaluated at compile time by mainstream compilers.  Unless you compile with `gcc -fno-builtin` (or `-ffreestanding`), then `strlen` isn't an alias for `__builtin_strlen`, and it doesn't assume anything about `strlen` being a pure function or doing what ISO C says it should.

Comment: @PeterCordes sorry I dont get you. Do you mean that `strlen()` might not be optimized to a constant at compile-time?

Comment: @D.J.Elkind: It will be optimized to a constant with `gcc` or `clang` with any `-O` option enabled.  I assume similar for MSVC and ICC.  In GCC/clang, one thing that can disable that optimization is `-fno-builtin-strlen`.  Unless you're writing a kernel you normally wouldn't use `-ffreestanding` or `-fno-builtin`, but I mention that for completeness.  See the `signal_handler` function in https://godbolt.org/z/x4d56o7Ec .  (I added `static const` to the msg array, otherwise GCC constructs it on the stack, but still knows the length unless you use `static` without `const`)

Comment: @PeterCordes, perhaps my [revision](https://github.com/alex-lt-kong/the-nitty-gritty/blob/2f5ecfb451793cb4d03e30d73f7042d6809e4d7d/c-cpp/common/04_posix-api/03_signal-handler/1_hello-world.c#L9-L15) is after you copied my code. In the current version, the msg is dynamic, I added signal number to the c-string. Btw, if `msg` is indeed static, what is the downside of storing it on stack, apart from using some stack space?

Comment: @D.J.Elkind: The downside is wasted instructions to store it there every time the function is invoked.  (With the ASCII data as immediates.  Or for larger strings, to run a memcpy to copy from .rodata.)  I copied the version of the code in the question, where `msg` is passed to `write` without being modified first.

Comment: On the downside, my thought could be a bit beyond this question: as the string is short, if we store it on stack, it will be close to other data, so we have the hope that it will be prefetched without complicated prefetching strategy. This gives me the feeling that it might not drag down the performance. But of course we have to benchmark different implementations to be certain.

Comment: Regarding the cast in `int tid = *((int*)param);` being redundant - as written, not it's not, because `param` is a `void *` so it can't be directly dereferenced. But it is possible (and maybe desirable) to remove the cast by doing `int *tid_ptr = param; int tid=*tid_ptr;`.

Comment: @psmears Good grief. Thanks for that.

Comment: @D.J.Elkind: Yes, it's true that stack space tends to be hot in cache, and that part of `.data` probably won't if you don't get signals often.  But signals are usually so rare that it's probably best to minimize overall code+data footprint.  Or if they're not, it will tend to still be hot in L2 or maybe L3 cache, and fewer instructions will execute every handler.  Also here, where your access to it is write-only before the system call, the store buffer can hide the latency of a cache miss store, overlapping with the time the CPU is switching to kernel mode and eventually doing `copy_from_user`

Answer (score 11):

In a multithreaded program, best practice is to *devote a thread to signal handling*.

Block all asynchronous signals<sup>1</sup> at the beginning of `main`, using `pthread_sigmask`, and leave them that way for the entire execution of the program (unless it spawns child *processes*; these will need to revert to the original signal mask before calling `execve`; but you do that *only* on the child side of the `fork`).

For each signal that you care about,<sup>2</sup> install a signal handler that does nothing; the only purpose of this is to ensure that none of these signals are set to be ignored.

Finally, create a thread that loops calling `sigwaitinfo` for all the signals you care about, and doesn't do any other work.  Do all of the processing of signal events in this thread's loop, not in handlers.  Communicate with other threads, using more ergonomic IPC mechanisms, as necessary.  Keep in mind that this thread is effectively an event-driven I/O handler, regardless of the architecture of the rest of your program; strive to make it do as little work as possible, and return to `sigwaitinfo` as quickly as possible.

<sup>1</sup> That is, all signal numbers except: SIGABRT, SIGBUS, SIGEMT (might not be defined), SIGFPE, SIGILL, SIGIOT (might not be defined and is likely to be equal to SIGABRT if it is), SIGSEGV, SIGSYS, and SIGTRAP.

<sup>2</sup> This must include at least the signals that notify you of user-initiated cancellation or suspension of your program: SIGHUP, SIGINT, SIGPWR, SIGQUIT, SIGTSTP, SIGTERM, SIGTTIN, SIGTTOU, and SIGXCPU.

Comment: what is the benefit of doing so, compared with call`pthread_join()` in the main thread and use `signal_handler()` in the main thread?

Comment: @D.J.Elkind: The biggest advantage is that, since you're not using a signal handler to do any work, you're not restricted in which functions you can call in response to the signal; it's also much easier to write code that doesn't have race conditions (which are a common issue with signal handlers due to their asynchronous nature).

Comment: @psmears I am actually not very sure how I can translate the words into code, do you have, say any links, that have some sample code which demonstrates the idea?

Comment: @D.J.Elkind: I don't, but it shouldn't be that complicated: as the answer says, (1) in your main thread, before creating any other threads, call `pthread_sigmask` to block all signals (this stops the signals getting delivered to the wrong place); (2) have a thread (it can be the main thread or one created with `pthread_create()`) call `sigwaitinfo()` in a `while` loop to detect signals and process them.

Comment: Yes, the biggest advantage of this approach is you never have to deal with signal concurrency (signals cause _worse_ concurrency headaches than threads since they can interrupt critical sections, including critical sections _inside the C library_ that you have no control over). Also, if there are multiple threads with a signal unblocked, then the kernel will choose one of them at random to run the signal handler, making things even more confusing than they already are.

Comment: @zwol I believe in my current design, concurrency should not be an issue as the `signal_handler()` does not use any shared resources. Do you think so?

Comment: @D.J.Elkind Yes, for your simple example program there is no signal concurrency issue; however, the virtue of the design I outlined is that _you don't have to think about whether there is a signal concurrency issue_ ever again.

Comment: @zwol do you have any links etc that translates the idea into concrete examples?

Comment: @D.J.Elkind No, but, like psmears says, it's really very simple.  What part of the idea is unclear from what I wrote?

Comment: emmmm....each line of code could be full of traps, just like the sample in my question--I prepared it carefully, still it has multiple issues, let alone to create one from some text description.